# How to query Elasticsearch to boost by specific field

Tags: python, elasticsearch

How do you index and query documents containing a custom weight so that you can use that weight to promote specific query results?

I've indexed simple documents with bodies like `{"text":"how now brown cow", "weight":2.3}`.

Using the Python wrapper, I can easily search these by doing:

```
es = Elasticsearch()
results = es.search(
    index='my_index',
    body={
        'query':{
            'query_string':{
                'query':my_search_terms,
            },
        },
    },
)
```

However, after reading the [docs](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html), I can't figure out how to incorporate the weight field so that results are boosted by this value. How would I do this?

Comment: Why not just use the `boost` attribute described in the [core types documentation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-core-types.html)?

Comment: @femtoRgon, I'm not sure that's what I want. That appears to assign a fixed weight to the field, when accumulating and calculating the score from matches in multiple fields, not just for a specific result. Also, it's unclear where I specify "properties". Attempting to pass it in the indexing JSON gives me an error.

Comment: Should be per field, per document, rather than a blanket for everything in that field (although you may be able to to that as well).  The simple example I see in the documentation is:  `{ "message" : { "_value":  "boosted value", "_boost":  2.0 } }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can do this with a [function_score query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-boost-field.html#function-score-instead-of-boost)

Something like:

```
{
"query": {
    "function_score": {
        "query": {  
            "match": {
                "text": "how now brown cow"
            }
        },
        "functions": [{
            "script_score": { 
                "script": "doc['weight'].value"
            }
        }],
        "score_mode": "multiply"
    }
}
}
```

Comment: `QueryParsingException[[howdoi] No query registered for [function_score]]; }]')`

Comment: What version of ElasticSearch are you using?

Comment: I've installed 0.20.6

Comment: Ah, function_score wasn't introduced until version 0.90.4, I believe.  0.90.0 was the first release with Lucene 4, which introduced some imrpovements to allow scoring on document contents with reasonable performance.  I think you may need to either rely on simple boosting, or upgrade elasticsearch.

Comment: Yep, that was the issue. Thanks.